# Blocking Microsoft websites big Image Slideshow Ads

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, opera, adblock

Today I was online looking for

Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter 3.0
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42497

It was showing me this:

[image]

And for a minute I was wondering why. I had to scroll down to see that I had relevant content below.

I had to zoom/ scale out to see the content and screenshot it.

This same area was used extensively through the whole "Upgrade to Windows 10" Campaign.

This stuff is fine on a Shop or Opening page, but not on every page.

Has someone figured out a way to block this?

I use a Chrome/ Opera Extension (Ublock Origin) to block ads, would it be possible to SUBMIT this or add this to it?

Or do I have to break my head with HOSTS files? Or some other hack/ Script way?

Comment: I know AdBlock has a "Block Element" option. Ublock may have a similar option.

Comment: @CConard96 It does.

Answer (score 1):

Used the "Element Picker" eye dropper feature of UBlock Origin in 3 steps 'picked' and 'created' the filters:

- Picked the 1st slide show image > Create
- Picked the next image > Create
- Picked the Slideshow driving Element itself > Create

Went into Ublock Origin's > My Filters and found 3 lines representing the filters that were created:

- Removed it (Since images will change often)
- Removed it (Since images will change often)
- `! 9/8/2016, 8:52:58 PM https://www.microsoft.com - Marketing Slide Shows
  www.microsoft.com###dlc-hp-hero-slideshow`

The last line is what you need to block the current Image heavy Slideshows from Microsoft's website.

The same procedure may be applied in the future as needed.

For additional information one can refer to the documentation around this:
https://github.com/gorhill/ublock/wiki/element-picker

Comment: The correct filter `###dlc-hp-hero-slideshow` could have been picked immediately in the first step. uBO offers a choice of filters from narrowest to broadest, and `###dlc-hp-hero-slideshow` was in there in the 1st attempt. After the 1st pick, this is merely a matter of selecting the proper entry in the list of suggested filters until finding one that does the job -- using _Preview_ to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

That depends. If you simply want to hide that entire container I'd recommend using `www.microsoft.com###dlc-hp-hero-slideshow`.

However, if you also want to prevent the images that are inside that container from downloading you need to add another filter along the lines of `||c.s-microsoft.com/*.jpg?version=$domain=www.microsoft.com`.

Note that most ad blockers offer some sort of manual element blocking functionality but the suggested filters you'll get might differ depending on which one you use.

See also [Adblock Plus filter syntax documentation](https://adblockplus.org/filters) for more information on writing filters.